# Creating dynamic variable in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have multiple strings like st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7. now i want to get that strings dynamically through for loop using its counter(in my case int i). like "st"+ i , but the android doesnot accept it so what should i do to get the string dynamically. for more info here is the chunk of the code

```
String image1 = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url1"));
String image2 = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url2"));
String image3 = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url3"));
String image4 = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url4"));
ArrayList<String> imagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();

 //for adding the string in the arraylist dynamically
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
    if("image"+i!=null){
        imagesArray.add(String.valueOf("image"+ i));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
List<String> imagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    String image = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url" + i));
    if (image != null) {
        imagesArray.add(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get value from cursor dynamically then change your code as:

```
 //for adding the string in the arraylist dynamically
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){

        int count = cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url"+i));
        if(count != -1)
         imagesArray.add(cData.getString(count)); 
}
```